# improve AS3 socket connecting time

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a small client build in flash(AS3) that connects to a server using the Socket class.

Everything works very fast when I'm testing the SWF from flash editor(CRTL+ALT+Enter), but when I'm embedding the swf into an html page the connection time is around 2-3 seconds which is a lot in my opinion.

I know that when I embed the flash into a html page it require to accept the socket policy before allowing me to connect to the server, however I realized that I receive the policy request only after 1 seconds the flash has been loaded.

To load the policy file I'm using:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://" + host + ":" + 16500);
```

So.. my question might become(I'm not 100% sure if this is the problem) how can I accelerate the policy request. Someone said on the forum(that I found on google) that the policy is send only when I want to send a message to server.

Do you know something about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem here it is normal.
When a socket connection is made the first thing that is done is the request for the policy file. After the server sends the policy file it will close the connection. After the client receives that file it should attempt to reopen the connection and keep it open. Now the socket is ready for data transfers.

So as you can see there is a lot of overhead here. The biggest overhead is the 2 connection attempts being made here.
When you embed the swf in a web page and access it over the web there is more over head. With DNS look ups and of course connection limitations.

So with all that being said. I can only think of 2 things that may help you.
First look into how master policy files work and load that one as soon as the swf inits.
And secondly study up on the different protocols that the Socket Class supports.
Maybe there is a faster one that is more suiting for you.
I can't suggest one because you did not state what your needs for the socket are and what protocol you are currently using.